# Can this be refactored to the more composable style seen in examples?

Tags: javascript, typescript, rxjs

I'm pretty new to rxjs and this example I've come up with doesn't feel so elegant. Essentially how can I compose 3 drastically different observables into one? Can you actually do it in the style of higher order functions like many of the examples online show?

```
createFilteredDataObservable(initialData: Observable<Data[]>,
                             valueSource: Observable<any>, 
                             clickSource: Subject<boolean>): Observable<Data[]> {
    let data: Data[] = [];
    let text = '';

    initialData.subscribe(value => {
      data= value;
    });

    function format(x: string): string {
      return x.toLowerCase().trim();
    }

    function filter() {
      if (text === '') {
        return data;
      }

      const result = data.filter(d=> {
        const name = format(d.DisplayName);
        return name === text || name.includes(text);
      });

      return result;
    }

    return new Observable<Data[]>((observer) => {

      clickSource.subscribe(_ => {
        const result = filter();
        observer.next(result);
      });

      valueSource.subscribe((v: string|Data) => {
        if (typeof v !== 'string') {
          return;
        }
        text = format(v);
        const result = filter();
        observer.next(result);
      });

    });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depends exactly what you're trying to do but roughly it should look something like...

```
const filtered = data.pipe(switchMap(data => {
  return value.pipe(startWith(''), combineLatest(clicks.pipe(startWith(null))), map(([value, _]) => {
    return data.filter(item => item.includes(value));
  }));
}));
```

Here is a Gist you can play with: https://gist.github.com/westonpace/4f7811b6735c94e97928be1bb6a377ce

I left out the `format` and simplified `filter` for brevity but that could be achieved by throwing a `map` on `value` between the `startWith` and the `combineLatest`.  This will behave different than your code in a few minor ways which you can tweak if you want.

In your example, if `initialData` is cold and takes a while to fire and `clickSource` and `valueSource` fire earlier then you could get an empty array.  In my example you will not get any results until `initialData` has fired at least once.  You could use `startWith` on `data` before the `switchMap` if you want this behavior.

Also, in your example, if `initalData` fired a second time then nothing would happen (the observable would continue to filter the old original value) where in this example if `initialData` fires again then it will switch over to filtering the new array but probably lose the value from `valueSource`.

In your example you will not get any results to start with and then the first result will arrive if either `clickSource` or `valueSource` fire.  I couldn't think of a way to replicate this exactly off the top of my head.  My code will fire once right away as soon as `data` fires.  If you leave off the `startWith` on `clicks` then it will fire only when `clickSource` fires.  If you leave off the `startWith` on `value` then it will fire only when `valueSource` fires at least once.  If you really need this behavior you could probably start, instead of `data.filter` with `merge(clicks, value).pipe(switchMap(_ => data.filter...`

Comment: It worked out great with only minor modifications. Thank you.